# Android SMS Broadcast Receiver Issue

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am unable to receive the broadcasts in my applications. I have requested the permissions and have been granted. Further, I have created broadcast receivers and registered them.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

MainActivity.java (onCreate)

```
        CheckAndGetPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, 10);
        CheckAndGetPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, 13);
        CheckAndGetPermission(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE, 11);
        CheckAndGetPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 12);

        private boolean CheckAndGetPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted " + permission , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

MainActivity.java (onResume)

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("SENT", "In Broadcast Receiver");

            }
        };

        smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("DELIVERY", "In Broadcast Receiver");
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
        registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));
    }
```

Update: @mike-m asked to see pending Indent. Here is the code sending SMS.

```
    private void SendSampleSms(String uuid) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        // Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("SMS_SENT");
        sendIntent.putExtra("type", "SMS_SENT");
        sendIntent.putExtra("uuid", uuid);
        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 100, sendIntent,0);
        // Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent();
        Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED");
        deliveryIntent.putExtra("type", "SMS_DELIVERED");
        deliveryIntent.putExtra("uuid", uuid);
        PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 100, deliveryIntent,0);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("*1111",null,"Sample Message",piSent,piDelivered);
    }
```

I was able to fix the problem. I was not setting `action` while creating Intent for PendingIntent, as seen in the lines commented in above method. After setting `action`, the broadcast receivers started receiving messages.

Comment: It's not quite clear which broadcasts you actually want. Those Receivers registered in code seem to be half of the setup needed for the message status reports available to all `SmsManager#send*()` methods. That is, they're only meant to tell you if your `sendTextMessage()` call, for example, was successful and if the service center has reported it as delivered to the recipient. Is that what you're trying to get working here? If so, we'd need to see the corresponding `PendingIntent`s and `send*()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. I have updated the post with code sending SMS message. I was able to fix the problem by setting `action` in intents used to create `PendingIntent`